# Counting number of integer solutions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many integer solutions are there to the equation $a + b + c = 21$ if $a \geq3$,
$b \geq 1$, and $c \geq 2b$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a = 3+A$, $b =1+B$, $c = 2b + d=2B+d+2$, the equation is $A + 3 B + d = 15$ with $A, B, d \ge 0$.  Now for each $B$ from $0$ to $5$, 
the number of $(A,d)$ pairs is $16 - 3 B$.  So...

Comment: So what?what to do next...

Comment: $16 + 13 + \ldots$

Comment: @RobertIsrael I think it is 15-3B?

Comment: Kumar, no, it must be $0\le B\le 4$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand why it is 16-3B?

Comment: The number of solutions of $x+y = m$ with nonnegative integers $x, y$ is $m+1$ (namely $x=0,y=m$, $x=1,y=m-1$, \ldots, $x=m, y=0$).

Comment: Kumar, I was mistaken, it must be $0\le B\le 5$ as stated in the answer. Also see Robert's comment for my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Brute forcing:
$$\begin{align}(a,b,c)=&(3,1,17), (3,2,16), (3,3,15), (3,4,14), (3,5,13), (3,6,12),\\
&(4,1,16), (4,2,15), (4,3,14), (4,4,13), (4,5,12),\\
&(5,1,15), (5,2,14), (5,3,13), (5,4,12), (5,5,11),\\
&(6,1,14), (6,2,13), (6,3,12), (6,4,11),\\
&(7,1,13), (7,2,12), (7,3,11), (7,4,10),\\
&(8,1,12), (8,2,11), (8,3,10), (8,4,9),\\
&(9,1,11), (9,2,10), (9,3,9),  (9,4,8),\\
&(10,1,10), (10,2,9), (10,3,8),\\
&(11,1,9), (11,2,8), (11,3,7),\\
&(12,1,8), (12,2,7), (12,3,6),\\
&(13,1,7), (13,2,6),\\
&(14,1,6), (14,2,5),\\
&(15,1,5), (15,2,4),\\
&(16,1,4),\\
&(17,1,3),\\
&(18,1,2).
\end{align}$$
Counting:
$$6+2\cdot 5+4\cdot 4+3\cdot 3+3\cdot 2+3\cdot 1=50.$$

Comment: You missed $(6,5,10)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, indeed, thank you for noting. I will not edit the post for ease of seeing.

Answer (score -3):

$a$ can vary from $3$ to $18$ $b$ can vary from $1$ to $16$ $c$ can vary from $2$ to $17$ Hence according to me number of solutions should be $16*16*16=4096$

Comment: $a$, $b$ and $c$ are not independent.

Comment: I know they are dependent thats why they have limited values